# nvidia drivers Multiple launchers

Tags: 12.04, gnome, launcher

I have recently changed a video card in my machine running Precise to GeForce and tried running it with native NVIDIA driver.

Now I have a problem because I have 2 monitors 22" wide and 19" VGA connected to the system and I have to use Xinerama with 2 independent monitors instead of TwinView.  Because of that I have 2 launchers (1 on each screen).

Is there a way to make sure that only 1 launcher is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apt-get install nvidia-settings` and then run it as root (`sudo nvidia-settings` works fine). You can choose which twin monitor set up you want from there and then log in/out again (or otherwise restart X).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that but my setup is Twinview so I'm not sure if it will work for you. Though it's worth a try. In System Settings > Display. There's an option Launcher placement where you can specify which monitor only will the launcher will appear, or all displays.